# Show data on recyclerView with paging libarary

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, pagination

I am using the paging library for pagination. everything works fine but there is a strange problem: I have an editText to getting the search value and a recyclerView. Whenever the data load into recyclerView it doesn't show up until I tap the edit text.

**Adapter**

```
class VendorListAdapter(var context: Context) :
PagedListAdapter<VendorItem, VendorListAdapter.VendorListViewHolder>(VENDOR_COMPARATOR) {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): VendorListViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_vendor, parent, false)
    return VendorListViewHolder(view)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: VendorListViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val vendorItem = getItem(position)

    vendorItem?.let {
        holder.bind(it)
    }
    }

class VendorListViewHolder(var view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

    private var title =view.textView_item_vendor_title

    fun bind(vendorItem: VendorItem){
        title.text = vendorItem.title
    }
}

companion object {
    private val VENDOR_COMPARATOR = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<VendorItem>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: VendorItem, newItem: VendorItem): Boolean {
            return oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: VendorItem, newItem: VendorItem): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }
    }
}}
```

this is where its load data to the recyclerView

```
viewModelVendor.searchPagedListLiveData.observe(this, Observer {
            progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
            vendorListAdapter.submitList(it)
            recyclerViewSearch.adapter = vendorListAdapter
        })
```

**DataSource**

```
class VendorListDataSource() : PageKeyedDataSource<Int, VendorItem>() {

private lateinit var accessToken: String
private lateinit var scope: CoroutineScope
private lateinit var requestVendorList: RequestVendorList
 var state: MutableLiveData<State> = MutableLiveData()
private var serv = RetrofitHelper.retrofitService(ApiVendor::class.java)

constructor(
    scopem: CoroutineScope,
    requestVendorListm: RequestVendorList,
    accessTokenm: String
) : this() {
    scope = scopem
    requestVendorList = requestVendorListm
    accessToken = accessTokenm
}


// It loads the first page of your data that use to initialize RecyclerView
@ExperimentalStdlibApi
override fun loadInitial(
    params: LoadInitialParams<Int>,
    callback: LoadInitialCallback<Int, VendorItem>
) {
    updateStatus(State.Loading)
    scope.launch {
        val response = serv.getVendorList(
            requestVendorList.categoryID,
            requestVendorList.cityID,
            requestVendorList.searchTitle,
            requestVendorList.pageSize,
            1,
            accessToken
        )

        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            val body = response.body()
            if (body != null) {
                if (body.successful) {
                    val vendorItemList = body.result
                    if (vendorItemList.size <= 0) {
                        updateStatus(State.EMPTY)
                    }
                    callback.onResult(vendorItemList, null, FIRST_PAGE + 1)

                } else {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@ExperimentalStdlibApi
override fun loadAfter(params: LoadParams<Int>, callback: LoadCallback<Int, VendorItem>) {
    updateStatus(State.Loading)
    scope.launch {
        val response = serv.getVendorList(
            requestVendorList.categoryID,
            requestVendorList.cityID,
            requestVendorList.searchTitle,
            requestVendorList.pageSize,
            params.key,
            accessToken
        )

        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            updateStatus(State.DONE)
            val body = response.body()
            if (body != null) {
                if (body.successful) {
                    val vendorItemList = body.result
                    val key = params.key + 1
                    vendorItemList.let {
                        callback.onResult(vendorItemList, key)
                    }
                } else {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//it used when to scroll up
@ExperimentalStdlibApi
override fun loadBefore(params: LoadParams<Int>, callback: LoadCallback<Int, VendorItem>) {
    updateStatus(State.Loading)
    scope.launch {
        val response = serv.getVendorList(
            requestVendorList.categoryID,
            requestVendorList.cityID,
            requestVendorList.searchTitle,
            requestVendorList.pageSize,
            params.key,
            accessToken
        )

        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            updateStatus(State.DONE)
            val body = response.body()
            if (body != null) {
                if (body.successful) {
                    val vendorItemList = body.result
                    val key = if (params.key > 1) params.key - 1 else 0
                    vendorItemList.let {
                        callback.onResult(vendorItemList, key)
                    }
                } else {

                }

            }
        }
    }
}

private fun updateStatus(state: State) {
    this.state.postValue(state)
}

companion object {
    const val FIRST_PAGE = 1
}
```

I have tried `notifyDatasetChanged`

Thank you for your help